# Ember JS Global Navigation Select Menu

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to figure out how build a customized Ember.Select control that acts as a kind of global navigation control.

See this example:

http://jsbin.com/ahERinI/1/

You will notice that the "local navigation pulldown" works just fine. But the "global navigation pulldown" does not.

The context of the ember select is not correct in the global case. But I am not quite sure how to setup the binding to get the behavior to work as expected.

I would also like to be able to place this control in a lot of different templates so would like to better understand how to setup the route and controller in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

really you are talking about it living at the application level.  You don't have access to the students controller always from the application level (it might not always exist).  So either you need to return the student models from the application controller, or do something else funky.

Here's an example of the first.

http://jsbin.com/oVoqUY/6/edit

```
 App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

   studModel: function(){
    return App.Student.find(); 
   }.property(),

   selectStudent: function(studentId){
    this.transitionToRoute('student', studentId);
   }

  });
```

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I didn't think about the computed property in ApplicationController. Clever! So in this instance will there be a XHR request every time that property is requested. SHould I put a .cacheable() on the end of that. Not sure how the observer behavior works in this situation.

Comment: Depending on the adapter you're using it might only make a single call.  Or you could always make the students route the default route for the application, and move that selector to the students template.  You also could grab the studModel from the application so it didn't make duplicate calls.  Personally I like the idea of the application just being an outlet, and always redirecting to the students level if the students global search will be available from anywhere in the app.